# How does a gas giant planet hold it's spherical shape when it has tidally locked rotation in it's orbit around the Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, planets, tidal-effect

How does a gas giant planet hold its spherical shape when it has a tidally locked rotation in its orbit around its Sun? Wouldn't it fall apart without its gravitational pull from the rotation? How does it hold its matter, especially in its spherical shape?

Comment: Gravitational pull does not come from rotation.

Comment: Also, a planet experiencing tides will not be perfectly spherical.  It's just that under the usual circumstance the effect is fairly small relative to the size of the planet. But they can get quite large. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit

Comment: Gas giants, notably, aren't spherical.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer the spherical geometry question first in order to build up to why it doesn't "fall apart". We know that the gravitational potential due to a continuous distribution of matter is:
$$ \Phi = -G \int_V \frac{\rho(r')}{r}dv'
$$
For $G$ as the gravitational constant, $\rho(r')$ as the density distribution over the body and $r$ the distance from the body to where we are studying the potential energy. For simplicity we will assume the gas giant in question is homogeneous (made from only one material) and therefore its density is constant such that:
$$\rho = \frac{m}{v}
$$
From this we will assume a spherical volume differential to study its energy such that:
$$\Phi = -G \int_0^{R'}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} r'^2\frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}d\theta d\phi dr'
$$
Remembering the law of cosines we can see:
$$ r^2 = r'^2 + R^2 -2r'R\cos(\theta)
$$
We would get:
$$\Phi = -\frac{4\pi}{3R}GR'^3
$$
Which is the minimal energy for any geometric shape (try it for yourself for a cube and a cylinder). As for why does the planet holds its shape, short answer is they don't, planets have a nonzero eccentricity due to a variety of factors it stays roughly the same shape because its own gravitational force is stronger on itself than the forces associated with gravitational pull from other planets and its movement.